# Wait to finish executing instruction in Python

Tags: python

How can I make Python wait for an instruction to finish executing?
I have an instruction that returns `True` when it finishes executing, so you must wait for it to go to the next line.

If I apply it line by line inside the Python terminal, it can be done, but if I put it inside a script to run it from the terminal, it doesn't execute the line.

```
import owncloud

oc = owncloud.Client ('https://xxx.xxxx.pe/cloud')

oc.login ('admin', 'PASSWORD')

oc.create_user ('uid', 'password')
True

print ("User created")
```

How do I get Python to execute line 4 and not jump to the next instruction until the value of the execution is True.
Right now as it is, it jumps to line 5 but does not finish executing line 4, because when I go to ownCloud to verify if the user was created, it does not appear. On the other hand, if I execute it line by line, the user is created.

Comment: Python executes code line by line. You most likely have a different error you aren't seeing in your code. If you open a brand new terminal instance and use just the lines above, does it make the new user?

Comment: How do you check if the user is created? If the user is eventually not really created, it could be that `oc.create_user()` is implemented asynchronously and the scripts executes so fast that there is no time to actually perform the action. A simple call to `time.sleep(1)` (or less) from the `time` module, could fix the issue.

Comment: @MasonCaiby there are cases when Python code is not executed sequentially, e.g. generators and coroutines.

Comment: @Marat, I'll agree that I oversimplified my wording, but Python DOES NOT support threading, because of its [GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Generators are built sequentially.

Comment: That particular function is synchronous; it executes fully before returning a value. You have some other problem there.

Comment: @norok2 Thanks for the reply.
The way I verify is by entering the credentials in the portal and I get that the user does not exist. I check at mysql level and it is also verified that the user was not created. I have already tried using time.sleep (20), but not even so.
If I execute it line by line inside the python terminal, it takes approximately 5 seconds and returns a value of True when it finishes executing. I imagine that some option of conditionals can be used.

Comment: @JotaPC have you tried sleeping before `oc.login()` too?

Comment: @norok2 Yes, But I don't succeed

Comment: My intention is to put it inside a loop because I have something of 200 users to create, but if I can't with this, I can't continue

Comment: Friends, I fixed it
What I did was put in a variable the user and password:
user = "12345678"
pass = "87654321"

oc.create_user (str (user), str (pass))

And with that he executed the script and created the user.

Comment: That's not the problem either; it can't be; a function has no way to know whether the values you're passing are in variables or not. But glad you got it working.